# Mute toggles on and off continuiously and launches Rhythmbox over and over

Tags: sound, mute

I have Ubuntu 14.04 starting in Nov 2014 on an HP-Pavilion-dv6700-Notebook-PC.  Loved Ubuntu at first, but then it started toggling the mute on the sound, varying every second to 10 seconds for several minutes at a time, and repeat. Sometimes several times a second.  Then it additionally starting launching Rhythmbox with different stations or files, over and over.  I have reinstalled 4 times and it keeps happening.  This is a stock laptop with no additional hardware than it came with.  This problem makes the computer unusable for extended periods of time.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: are there any media keys or controls on your laptop - those that launch media apps and/or changes the sound.  Your question sounds like the keys/controls are stuck down/faulty.

Comment: Does anything like this happen when running a different OS, windows, other live linux's or older/newer Ubuntu's? If it is a button malfunctioning, does jiggling or pushing the button do anything?

Comment: fossfreedom, yes, my keyboard does have these keys, but they are not stuck and work - all of them.  In between the toggles I can temporarily undo the mute with the keyboard keys.   Thanks.

Comment: Xen2050, This problem didn't happen in Windows Vista.   I no longer have Vista it on the machine, though.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your internal keyboard got wet.  I've found [a replacement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GTXGVO) under $15.

**Likely cause:**  Given the season, bringing your laptop in from the cold can cause enough condensation to form on electronics to cause all sorts of misbehavior and even permanent damage.  If that's the case it is impossible to tell if a new keyboard will fix it, or if it could just dry out and work properly given time.  If you think the problem could be condensation you should shut the laptop down, remove all power, including its battery, and stand the lap on edge, lid open, preferably near a heating vent or at least a desk fan to help dry it out.

(Update below follows comment by OP)
**Next step in diagnostics:**
Obviously you seem to think the problem is software, not hardware.  An easy way to find out is to boot the computer to ubuntu on cd/dvd or USB flash media.  If the problem continues then the odds are you are seeing a hardware problem.  If the problem does not continue then you would appear to be correct that the problem is somehow related to Ubuntu, component drivers, or some misbehaving and unwanted update.  Although I've seen incompatibilities between certain brands of computers and Ubuntu, it was never a brand like HP, Dell or Lenovo.  It was always Toshiba.  I like toshiba, but I must assume they are not sharing their firmware or whatever with Linux developers.

Comment: gyropyge, That is not the case here.  But you do have me thinking about static as it is dry here.   I will keep this in mind and troubleshoot further, but I think this is a long shot.   Thanks.